# How to start a existing (but stopped) container with interactive terminal?

Tags: docker

I'm new to Docker and had googled about my question.

Is there a way to start a existing (but stopped) container with interactive terminal?

The answer I found is giving **interactive** and **attached** flag (i&t) when starting a container. The command I gave is:

```
docker start -ia <container_name>
```

But the container always stops immediately.

Otherwise, if I run image to create a new container with this command, it would sustain:

```
docker run -it <image_name>
```

The reason I want to reuse the container instead of create a new one every time is that I want to use a container as a sandbox or development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first run the container in interactive mode using `docker run -it <image_name>`

Now you can exit the terminal safely with <kbd>ctrl p</kbd> <kbd>ctrl q</kbd>

Then you can use `docker exec -it <container_name> /bin/bash` to get into an already running container or use `docker start -ia <container_name>` to start a stopped container.

The reason your container is "always stops immediately" may be because you run it in detached mode with `-d` option, in which case docker runs the container and exits immediately since there are no processes to run. Running the container with `-it` option starts it with the `/bin/bash` command.

Comment: You're right, I should create a container with -it options. Thank you!